I find an error when I try the RDLC report viewer in C# Visual Studio
This is a screenshot of the error that appears when I try the RDLC report viewer in C# Visual studio. What can I do? Please help
enter image description here
I tried to generate reports for the software I created. So I tried using Report viewer. But I couldn't do it because when I try to drag and drop the report viewer, the error appears as in the screenshot

Did you add  the reportviewer.common package reference?

Right click your project ->  Manage NuGet packages -> search reportviewer.common.
Install  Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common
